# In-game Air Traffic Control questions

Tags: air-traffic-control

I have been making an AI ATC for a game I have been writing. The channel is mostly dead air but occasionally you can hear some chatter:

http://reskin.us:8081/stream

I am a former airline pilot and a few scenarios come up frequently in the game which I don't have experience with in RL (luckily):

1) Aircraft flying through the class B without talking to approach

2) Aircraft establishing communication with ATC when already inside the class B

3) VTOL operations - to separate aircraft I understand they fly a very normal approach to the airport but then are treated like rotorcraft after that? Do they hand you over to ground control when you are over the numbers or how is that coordinated?

Any controllers out there know what they would say in these cases (if anything) over the radio?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ATC will try to contact the unknown aircraft on the sector frequency and, if that fails, on Guard.  Since they don't have a tail number, they'll call the aircraft by location and altitude (e.g. unknown aircraft 4 miles northwest of XXX at 3500 feet).  At the same time, they'll begin vectoring other traffic away from it to maintain separation; this is similar to how Center/Approach will vector IFR traffic around unknown VFR traffic in Class E airspace, except in Class B they'll also be vectoring VFR traffic (rather than giving mere traffic advisories) as well.  There will likely be missed approaches, TCAS RAs, etc. that have to be dealt with as well.  Still, the only real difference with this happening in Class B vs Class C/D is the staggering volume of traffic affected.

ATC may in some cases ask a friendly pilot in the right place to try to identify the violator.  I've been asked to do that once; we weren't fast enough to get the tail number, but we did identify it as a low-wing single at the reported altitude, which was still useful info for ATC.  I don't know what happened after ATC vectored us back on course; this was years before LiveATC existed.

If/when communication is established, ATC will inform the pilot they're in the Bravo, give them a squawk code and vector them out as quickly and directly as possible without further disruption to traffic flows--without regard for the pilot's desired course.  They'll also ask them to "copy the phone number", as with other violations.  Don't expect any favors from ATC after that, of course, but they're as calm and professional as usual once the immediate safety problem is resolved.

I don't know anything personally about VTOL operations, but I'd assume they'd stay with Tower just like a helicopter--either "cleared to land" on the runway or "land at your own risk" somewhere else on the airport--and wouldn't go to Ground until/unless they needed to taxi within the movement area.